# UICollectionView tvOS cells are not rendering on Apple TV

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos, apple-tv

I'm developing an application for tvOS. It has a tableview and each row of the tableview contains a collectionview. Tableview's focus is disabled so that collectioview cells get focused. When I return a static number as the collectionview items count, the cells are rendered. But when the items count is set dynamically, the cells are not rendered.

The code I used is given below:

```
class CategoryCVContainerCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryCollectionView: UICollectionView!


    var cellType:CellType?

    var sourceViewController: UIViewController?

    var media : Media?



    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        categoryCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "VODType1CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "VODType1CollectionViewCell")

    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state

    }


    func configureCellUI() {

        categoryCollectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0))

    }

}

extension CategoryCVContainerCell : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("////////************------------////////// \(categoryDetails?.media?.count ?? 0)")

        let itemsCount = categoryDetails?.media?.count ?? 0    //this code won't render cells

        // let itemsCount = 10 // this code works

        return itemsCount

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VODType1CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 250.0)

    }  

}
```